# libxml2: Special characters in xmlNewChild()

Tags: xml, special-characters, libxml2

This is likely a very stupid question, but I'd be grateful for any help.  I'm using libxml2 to build an XML file out of data in an sql database.  So I'm looping over fields in the sql table and doing things like:

```
xmlNewChild(node, NULL, (xmlChar*) template[i].c_str(), (xmlChar*) data[i].c_str());
```

Producing the XML:

```
<template>data</template>
```

Now, for a very few of these, I want to be sneaky and put another subnode in by setting `data[i]` equal to a string containing XML.  So, for example, I want to set `data[i]` to `<subnode>text</subnode>`  so that the resulting XML would be:

```
<template><subnode>text</subnode></template>
```

However, in the XML, these are always rendered `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
<template>&lt;subnode&gt;text&lt;/subnode&gt;</template>
```

Is there a way to preserve the angular brackets?  I thought that using `xmlNewChild()` instead of `xmlNewTextChild()` would preserve the characters, but it apparently does not.  Is there a way to put a string containing angular brackets into `data[i]` and have those brackets preserved in the XML that is built?

(I realize that sneaking additional xml tags in this way seems like a somewhat sketchy practice, but in my case it would really be much simpler than figuring out which of the many fields will need subnodes and then building those subnodes in the standard way).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. You need to parse the subnode first, and then add that to the parent.

Comment: As I feared.  Unfortunately, I can't just parse the subnode first, because the code that builds the XML doesn't know which nodes will require subnodes and which will just contain text.

Comment: Really you want to parse it as "element content" that can be either text or sub-elements, similar to parsing innerHTML in the JavaScript DOM. I don't think libxml2 has a convenient function for that, but you could probably hack one together using the xmlReader interface. Or just store the data differently. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, libxml2 will always escape tags in content.  I'd thought [xmlNodeSetContent](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeSetContent) and  [xmlNodeAddContent](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeAddContent) varied in this regard, but they don't - it's only for entity references, such as `&#169;`.  SetContent will include that literally as a "real" entity reference, but AddContent will escape it to `&amp;#169;`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried doing: `xmlNode * childNode = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, (xmlChar*) template[i].c_str(), NULL);` and then `xmlNodeSetContent(childNode,(xmlChar*) data[i].c_str())` but the result is still `&lt;TEST&gt;` where data[i] had been `<TEST>`.  This is the same behaviour as when I just used xmlNewChild(), which also supposedly doesn't escape special characters.

Comment: You're right.  I thought I'd used it for that purpose before, but I must be remembering wrong.  Sorry about that.